# Scraping Google Maps with Python and bs4 Without API

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm triying get data from google maps with python and BeautifulSoup. For example pharmacies in a city. I will get location data (lat-lon), name of pharmacy(ie, MDC Pharmacy), score of pharmcy(3.2), number of rewiews(10), addres with zip code, and phone number of pharmacy.
I have tried python and BeautifulSoup but I'm stuck because I don't know how to extract the data. Class method isn't working. When I prettifing and printing to the results I have seen all of data. So how can I clean them for a pandas data frame? I need more codes both for clean data and add them a list or df. Also classobject turning noobject type. Here my codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("https://www.google.com.tr/maps/search/eczane/@37.4809437,36.7749346,57378m/data=!3m1!1e3")
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
a=soup.prettify()
l=soup.find("div",{"class":"mapsConsumerUiSubviewSectionGm2Placeresultcontainer__result-container mapsConsumerUiSubviewSectionGm2Placeresultcontainer__one-action mapsConsumerUiSubviewSectionGm2Placeresultcontainer__wide-margin"})
print(a)
```

[Printresult.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB9Yo.jpg)

I have this result I need extract data from here (above).

I want a result like this table (below). Thanks...

[wanted resul(it is just a sample)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGoh.jpg)

Comment: If you can see it in the BS4 results, then clearly you can extract it from the string.  So what's your question?

Comment: By the way, that data is all in the Javascript block.  You would be able to pull individual HTML tags.

Comment: Hi, Tim thanks for your interest. I know I can extract them. But I cant find a way extract them a list or turn them a table. I cant find tags. I cant see lat-lon classes source of page(in my url). Can you do a sample? Searching pharmacies in Google maps. And extract information of result? Thanks your interest again.

Comment: Here's what you can observe.  The data you want is part of a big JSON structure, called `APP_INITIALIZATION_STATE`.  You can fetch that JSON code using simple `string.find` operations, then you can use `json.loads` to convert that to a Python dictionary.  After that, it's just finding the right elements in those lists.

Comment: Thanks. I tried. But couldnt (JSONDecodeError: Expecting value). I need sample codes for solutions.

Comment: IO have some answer that I need use selenium. I will try with selenium.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need selenium for this.  You don't even need BeautifulSoup (in fact, it doesn't help at all).  Here is code that fetches the page, isolates the initialization data JSON, decodes it, and prints the resulting Python structure.

You would need to print out the structure, and start doing some counting to find the data you want, but it's all here.

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
r=requests.get("https://www.google.com.tr/maps/search/eczane/@37.4809437,36.7749346,57378m/data=!3m1!1e3")

txt = r.text

find1 = "window.APP_INITIALIZATION_STATE="
find2 = ";window.APP"

i1 = txt.find(find1)
i2 = txt.find(find2, i1+1 )
js = txt[i1+len(find1):i2]
data = json.loads(js)
pprint(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But I was getting before too. May be I cannot explain my problem. My problem starting at here. I can't find a way to extract the data from this (At the your code from data variable). At my code a variable is similar data. I want extract data and create a list or dataframe or excell sheet. I will reedit my question. Thanks your interest again.

Comment: doesn't work anymore thanks to cooky consensus

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's exactly the code I was looking for , for a long time now. Man, do I love SO !

Answer (score 0):

It might be also worth looking into a third party solution like SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "secret_api_key",
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "q": "eczane",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "hl": "en",
  "ll": "@37.5393407,36.707705,11z",
  "type": "search"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"local_results": [
  {
    "position": 1,
    "title": "Ocak Eczanesi",
    "place_id": "ChIJcRipbonnLRUR4DG-UuCnB2I",
    "data_id": "0x152de7896ea91871:0x6207a7e052be31e0",
    "data_cid": "7063799122456621536",
    "reviews_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=0x152de7896ea91871%3A0x6207a7e052be31e0&engine=google_maps_reviews&hl=en",
    "photos_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=0x152de7896ea91871%3A0x6207a7e052be31e0&engine=google_maps_photos&hl=en",
    "gps_coordinates": {
      "latitude": 37.5775156,
      "longitude": 36.957789399999996
    },
    "place_id_search": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data=%214m5%213m4%211s0x152de7896ea91871%3A0x6207a7e052be31e0%218m2%213d37.5775156%214d36.957789399999996&engine=google_maps&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&type=place",
    "rating": 3.5,
    "reviews": 8,
    "type": "Drug store",
    "address": "Kanuni Mh. Milcan Cd. Pk:46100 Merkez, 46100 Dulkadiroğlu/Kahramanmaraş, Turkey",
    "open_state": "Closes soon ⋅ 6PM ⋅ Opens 8:30AM Fri",
    "hours": "Closing soon: 6:00 PM",
    "phone": "+90 344 231 68 00",
    "website": "https://kahramanmaras.bel.tr/nobetci-eczaneler",
    "thumbnail": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipN5CQRdoKc_BdCgSDiEdi0nEkk1X_VUy1PP4wN3=w93-h92-k-no"
  },
  {
    "position": 2,
    "title": "Nobetci eczane",
    "place_id": "ChIJP4eh2WndLRURD6IcnOov0dA",
    "data_id": "0x152ddd69d9a1873f:0xd0d12fea9c1ca20f",
    "data_cid": "15046860514709512719",
    "reviews_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=0x152ddd69d9a1873f%3A0xd0d12fea9c1ca20f&engine=google_maps_reviews&hl=en",
    "photos_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=0x152ddd69d9a1873f%3A0xd0d12fea9c1ca20f&engine=google_maps_photos&hl=en",
    "gps_coordinates": {
      "latitude": 37.591462,
      "longitude": 36.8847051
    },
    "place_id_search": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data=%214m5%213m4%211s0x152ddd69d9a1873f%3A0xd0d12fea9c1ca20f%218m2%213d37.591462%214d36.8847051&engine=google_maps&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&type=place",
    "rating": 3.3,
    "reviews": 12,
    "type": "Pharmacy",
    "address": "Mimar Sinan, 48007. Sk. No:19, 46050 Kahramanmaraş Merkez/Kahramanmaraş, Turkey",
    "open_state": "Open now",
    "thumbnail": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNznf-hC_y9KdijwUMqdO9YIcn7rbN8ZQpdIHK5=w163-h92-k-no"
  },
  ...
]
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*